# Custom routing in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I know most asp.net routes are defined as shown below

```
myweb.com/products/{name}/{id}/{title}
```

However, I am trying to set up custom URL routing where the pattern is like

```
mywebsite.com/{name}/{id}/{title}
```

All three parameters are required and are all dynamic. Is there a way for .NET MVC to handle such a pattern through a controller?

Can anyone help?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
routes.MapRoute(
       name: "custom",
       template: "{name}/{id}/{title}",
       defaults: new { controller = "Products" });
```

Note that the order in which you add the routes is important. Try not to put this route below another that would catch the expected URLs.

Comment: it's so weird that you just copied my answer and get marked!

Comment: @ElyasEsna if you look closer, you will see that I provided a slightly different answer than yours. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

just add your pattern to the route list:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "custom",
                template: "{controller}/{name}/{id}/{title}");
        });
```

Comment: I am sorry, I do not understand the pattern to the route list, your example is missing the {name} parameter. Also, how do I tell it what controller to use

Comment: see the update, put this code in Configure method (before default route) of startup.cs

Comment: tried that, but it doesn't seem to be working. I've tried a whole bunch of other things including, ```app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "custom",
                template: "{controller=Handler}/{name}/{id}/{title}");
        });```

Comment: when you specify the route you should provide name, id and title for all of your actions as input parameters

Answer (score -2):

Your pattern should be as 
defaults: new {controller = "controller name", action = "action name of the controller", id= UrlParameter.Optional}